# Using sites with a Sandbox (my force.com sites is live, but I need to test changes) - how to?

Tags: managed-package, force.com-sites, sandbox

I'm using a managed package called Fairsail in Salesforce, which uses Force.com sites to create a job applicant portal. I need to make some changes to test a new job vacancy, but I need to do it in a sandbox or sandbox-like environment (so job applicants don't see the test vacancy). I found this article: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000193345&language=en_US but am not sure it's the solution I need. How can I best make changes to my Force.com Sites page and test all the functionality while still keeping my existing Force.com Sites page live? 
I thought when Fairsail trained me there was an alternate URL for the Force.com Sites - like maybe with the word 'test' in it - does that sound right?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be challenging because if the managed package is using code and redirecting to the site not using a relative URL it could be directing subsequent pages to the prod site (may not be happening but could be an issue).

There should be a custom setting or something that you can alter to provide the sandbox site URL instead of the prod URL.

setup -> develop -> custom settings

If any of your site pages have been custom built you will need to update any references to the page URLs to reference the test site pages as well.

If you do not know what you are looking at I would suggest to get Fairsail support team on a call and discuss it with them as they would be best suited to help with their package.

Unfortunately, without knowing the details / code involved with your site there is not any direct changes that can be recommended here. BUT, in general, find all references to the prod site and change them to the test site. You should look in custom settings, apex classes, and visual force pages associated with the site.

Also, you can test the site pages directly modifying the url to include the `/apex/` before the page name:

i.e

https://xxx.salesforce.com/SitePage

to

https://xxx.salesforce.com/apex/SitePage

BUT, depending on the requirements of the page (check if portal user, expecting a contact to be associated with the user, etc) it may not work. Also, if you click on buttons or links that take you to another page, and those links use a custom setting or non relative url it will revert back tot he site page...

> <strike>If you would like to get on a phone call and screen share I can walk
>   you through some of this as it is easier to talk through that on a
>   message board. If this options is good for you post a comment below
>   and I will set up a throw away email address you can send your info to
>   and I will reply with my number.</strike>